# Differences between "Click Classes" and "Click Element" in Google Tag Manager

Tags: css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I don't really understand the differences between *Click classes* and *Click Element* in Google Tag Manager. I don't understand the expected use of these event and I don't understand their respective behavior regarding *contains* and *CSS selector*.

Let's say I have `class="buttons primary small"`.

What's working:

```
Click Element -> Matches CSS selector -> .buttons.small 
Click Classes -> contains -> small
```

What's not working:

```
Click Element -> contains -> .buttons.small 
Click Classes -> Matches CSS selector -> small
```

If Click Classes is "an array of the classes on an object", what really happens *under the hood* of GTM when doing this kind of manipulation?

I don't have real issues, I'm just trying to understand it properly.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Click Classes returns the value of the `class` attribute of the HTML element that was the target of the action. It is always a string, and in your example would return "buttons primary small" though not necessarily in that order.

Click Element returns the HTML element that was the target of the action.

"contains" is a match type in GTM that you use against strings. That's why it works with Click Classes (which returns a string) and not Click Element.

"Matches CSS Selector" is a check whether any given element matches a given CSS selector. "Matches CSS Selector" must thus be done against an HTML element. That's why it works with Click Element and not Click Classes.

In my opinion, Click Classes is redundant, since you're always better off doing a CSS selector check against Click Element rather than a string match against Click Classes. It's more robust that way, and you also don't need to worry about the class names being in a certain order in the class attribute value.

In other words, **better**:

Click Element **matches CSS selector** .buttons.primary.small

**Worse**:

Click Classes **contains** buttons primary small

Comment: When you just search for a button-Tag, then you receive "[object HTMLButtonElement]". To match it set the rule to *contains "Button"*. (note the uppercase B).

Comment: Or just use a CSS selector, again: Click Element **matches CSS selector** `button`. That will match all clicked elements that were `<button>` HTML elements.

Comment: In tagassistant however, it says: Click Element, Data Layer, Variable: string. That makes it so confusing. Certainly because in my head, like you said, contains is something you can use against a string. Which tagassistant says it is...