# Click Class and Element not working on GTM [SOLVED]

Tags: google-tag-manager

I read this valuable [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477486/differences-between-click-classes-and-click-element-in-google-tag-manager/75772746#75772746) and also this [article](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/click-element-variable-in-google-tag-manager/).

But both didn't address the issue I have...
I want to create a trigger for a click on an element similar to this:

```
<div class="parent foo">
    <div class="some other div with tons of class names"
         <div class="child bar">
</div></div></div>
```

So the full css selector is: `.parent.foo .some.other.div.with.tons.of.class.names .child.bar`

In reality, I want an event for our social icon click, but I want to differentiate between the header and the footer, and the sidebar locations.

I was trying these 2 approaches:

(1)

```
Click Classes -> contains -> parent
AND Click Element -> contains -> child
```

(2)

```
Click Element -> Matches CSS selector -> .parent .child
```

Both didn't work.

Does someone have a suggestion?

---

### UPDATE + Solution

I misrepresented the issue I had. Apparently, the click-element according to GTM was the icon inside the div I was trying to catch. Meaning, I wanted to catch the whole button area, but as for GTM, I actually clicked on the icon inside the button.
So, instead of using CSS selector = `.parent .child`
I should use: `.parent .child *`
and this solved it for me :)

The correct html representation should be:

```
<div class="parent foo">
    <div class="some other div with tons of class names"
         <div class="child bar">
            <i class="facebook-icon"></i>
</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First, don't test your selectors through GTM. Test them either through your console, or better yet through the DOM search in your dev tools. Just go to the Elements tab in devtools and search there for your selector. The search there is very intelligent and is capable of reading CSS selectors seamlessly.

Your CSS selector has an error. A space. Remove it.

If you're familiar with JS, you don't need to make three selectors. Make one that would match all three locations and then use a CJS variable that would analyse the parent of the `{{Click Element}}` and return the location as needed.

If this still doesn't address your issue, show us your updated selectors, pieces of HTML that you want to match and a screenshot from the preview debugger that shows the value of your Click Element variable on every click.